# What Class of Electricians Glove Do I need to work inside my electric panel

Tags: electrical-panel

I need access to the main power lines coming into my electrical panel (split single phase with 120V in each line) in order to clamp CTs around each line. The incoming lines are 'hidden' behind a removable panel in the box. Due to the somewhat close proximity of this cover to the live breaker bars, I would prefer to be protected. Thanks.

Comment: You may want to make sure your panel can actually use normal CTs. See for example [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/273610/is-electrical-panel-safe-after-arc-flash) about a case where they didn't work.

Comment: Gloves won't protect you from **arc flash** when you manage to short the cover or your screwdriver across the live bus bars, for instance.

Answer (score 8):

Class 00 gloves are good for up to 500 volts AC and 750 volts DC. Contact your power company and see if they'll come out and temporarily disconnect your power, pull the meter, so your panel is de-energized while you do the work. They could require an inspection before reconnecting it though. Live panels are nothing to mess with if you're not properly trained. You might want to seek some professional help.

Comment: Most decent power companies allow you at least one free disconnect, if you ask and give them some time.

Comment: @crip659  I agree but they might require an inspection before reconnecting.

Comment: Not for adding CTs I wouldn't think.  And they can "pull a meter" remotely - at least they did in 2012 on a podunk backwater rural electrification (though who knows, maybe they were the first to go to smart meters due to more costly to go from ranch to ranch than walk down a dense urban street getting 20 readings in 1 block).

Comment: In urban areas our utility was installing smart meters 20+ years ago. The tech was getting good, and nobody wanted to actually go and read meters.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica   I would much rather have a mechanical disconnect seen, than hoping someone miles away does not flip a switch/command back on.  I believe in Murphy.

Comment: @crip659  In Florida, they have the smart meters and will use remote disconnect for nonpayment and vacant apartments but not for a disconnect where work is to be done on th panel. For that, they send out a crew.