What are these mains in my home's electrical panel?
I was planning to install an Emporia Vue in my home's electrical box but have never seen a main power supply that wasn't an insulated wire. What are these that look like brackets and can I safely install an energy monitor (which requires a sensor around the mains)?
Photos below



Those look like bus bars coming from the meter just to the left. One would need to check the instructions for the particular panel, but bus bars are fine and ordinary power distribution options in many cases.

Before trying to fit CTs, please read https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/273610/is-electrical-panel-safe-after-arc-flash

Insulation can be air.  Insulation is only really needed where a conductor might touch another grounded surface, or where people might lick them.

They are bus bars, one of them appears to be completely uninsulated, the other barely so.
They will also be hot at all times (presumably) because they appear to be coming direct from your electric meter. That also means they are effectively unfused (or "current limited by impedance" at some absurd level like 10,000 or 22,000 Amps) - plenty to vaporize metal and other fun things with damaging side effects.
Attempting to use a current transformer intended for a wire may have disastrous effects, as in this related question. Without having the power company pull the meter, or them approving you pulling the meter, the best bet is to stay the heck away from them. It's possible that someone may make a special CT that will work on them, but installing such here would be very hazardous without getting power turned off, first.

Emporia makes flexible 200A sensors For use on bus bars like these.  Don't try to use the included 200A CTs there.
Installation of the flexible sensors on live bus bars before the main breaker is dangerous.   If you don't have the right equipment and experience to do that, have an electrician do it.  That will take 5 minutes and probably be cheaper and easier than having the meter turned off.
You might be able to fit the flexible sensors on the short bit of busbar between the main breaker and the first pair.  You can try that with the power off. I don't think they'll fit.
